# overloading the extraction operator to initialize an std::array<double, N>

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading data from a file of the type `(0 0 0)` which I would like to put in a `std::array`.

When I compile the code I get an error saying that the `>>` is not overloaded.

I have:

```
#include <array>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>


int main(int argCount, char *args[])
{

    std::string tst ("(0 0 0)");

    std::istringstream is (tst);

    std::array<double, 3> myVec; 

    is >> myVec;

    return 0;
}
```

I, afterwards, defined the overloading of the `>>`operator to collect the data in the following way:

```
template <typename std::size_t N>
std::istringstream& operator>> (std::istringstream& is, std::array<double, N>& v)
{
    char c1 ;

    is >> c1;

    if(c1 != '(')
    {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        is >> v[i];
    }

    is >> c1;

    if(c1 != ')')
    {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    
    return is;
}
```

Is this a correct solution for overloading the extraction operator?

Comment: Does it work? Why do you think there might be a problem with it?

Comment: Well, did you try it, and see if it works? Did it work correctly? If not, why not?

Comment: for me it works, but I am very new to C++ and to not know if I should put something else in the overloading to make it more complete

Comment: @ThomasJerry The only problem that I think is that you need to have your `>>` inside your operator in `if` condition. for example: `if (!(is >> v[i])) return is;` because you have no check for failing reading stream itself.

Comment: Would you mind putting it in a reply?

Comment: Can you provide the compiler output?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.